# Error after installation on host with telemetry.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, netlify

I'm getting an error when trying to build my Gatsby JS application on Netlify. Does anybody have an idea of what this error could be?

Error:

```
4:53:02 PM: $ gatsby build
4:53:02 PM: /opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/telemetry.js:39
4:53:02 PM:   store = new _eventStorage.EventStorage();
4:53:02 PM:         ^
4:53:02 PM: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
4:53:02 PM:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
4:53:02 PM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
4:53:02 PM:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
4:53:02 PM:     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
4:53:02 PM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
4:53:02 PM:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
4:53:02 PM:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
4:53:02 PM:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/gatsby-telemetry/lib/index.js:21:18)
4:53:02 PM:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
4:53:02 PM:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
4:53:02 PM: ​
4:53:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4:53:02 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
4:53:02 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
4:53:02 PM: ​
4:53:02 PM:   Error message
4:53:02 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: gatsby build
4:53:02 PM: ​
4:53:02 PM:   Error location
4:53:02 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
4:53:02 PM:   gatsby build
4:53:02 PM: ​
4:53:02 PM:   Resolved config
4:53:02 PM:   build:
4:53:02 PM:     command: gatsby build
4:53:02 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
4:53:02 PM:     publish: /opt/build
```

Comment: Does it build locally?

Answer (score 0):

First delete delete `node_modules` `package-lock,json` `yarn.lock` also the `cache` and `public` folder created by Gatsby.

Then try running the following command in your project directory terminal : -

```
npm cache verify
npm cache clean
npm install
npm audit fix
```

THEN

`npm start` `gatsby develop`  `gatsby build`
If it builds successfully clean the Gatsby `cache` & `public` directory and deploy to netifly.